# Padrão MVC Web com NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Galera, não estou achando nada relacionado, é o seguinte:
Estou aprendendo o modelo MVC, usando o módulo Express (NodeJS), conexão com MySQL Ok e já tem até uma interaçãozinha entre as páginas na WEB, tudo beleza até agora, mas tem um problema. Não faço ideia de como exibir o resultado da consulta **personalizado** numa página HTML, o máximo que já consegui foi exibir com JSON transformando em String e setando na tela.

```
exports.exibirCarros = (req, res) => {
let query = 'SELECT * FROM carros';

let result = pool.query(query, (err, rows) => {
   if(err) console.log(err);

   let vetor = [];

  // vetor.push(JSON.stringify(rows));
   rows.map((todo) => vetor.push(todo.cor));
  //  console.log(vetor);
   return vetor;  
});
console.log(result);

res.render('pages/showCars');
```

}

Dentro do escopo do 'pool.query()', eu consigo o array que eu quero exibindo a variável 'vetor' :

```
[ 'Vermelho', 'Preto', 'Vermelho', 'Verde', 'Vermelho', 'Preto' ]
```

Agora quando dou um 'console.log(result)', eu nem sei o que significa isso:

```
    <ref *1> Query {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: [Function (anonymous)],
  _callSite: Error
      at Pool.query (/home/carlos/Documentos/JavaScript/example_MVC_FullWeb/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:199:23)
      at exports.exibirCarros (/home/carlos/Documentos/JavaScript/example_MVC_FullWeb/controllers/carroController.js:14:23)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/carlos/Documentos/JavaScript/example_MVC_FullWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at next (/home/carlos/Documentos/JavaScript/example_MVC_FullWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
      at Route.dispatch (/home/carlos/Documentos/JavaScript/example_MVC_FullWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/carlos/Documentos/JavaScript/example_MVC_FullWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at /home/carlos/Documentos/JavaScript/example_MVC_FullWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
      at Function.process_params (/home/carlos/Documentos/JavaScript/example_MVC_FullWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
      at next (/home/carlos/Documentos/JavaScript/example_MVC_FullWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
      at Function.handle (/home/carlos/Documentos/JavaScript/example_MVC_FullWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3),
  _ended: false,
  _timeout: undefined,
  _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular *1], _timeout: null },
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM carros',
  values: undefined,
  typeCast: true,
  nestTables: false,
  _resultSet: null,
  _results: [],
  _fields: [],
  _index: 0,
  _loadError: null
}
```

[Código-fonte](https://github.com/Jackie098/Exemplo_MVC_com_Node)

Comment: Você deve renderizar a página dentro do _callback_ de `pool.query`, que retorna um objeto porque a consulta SQL é executada assíncronamente

Comment: Fiz isso e ele me retornou um erro bem louco ->
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
    at ServerResponse.header ...

Comment: E aí cara, não sei o que estava fazendo de errado, mas tentei de novo e deu certo quanto ao callback, vlw aí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amigo, tudo bem?

Utilizando Node.js você não consegue exibir conteúdo dinâmico dentro de uma página HTML. Para fazer isso, existe um pacote chamado EJS, feito exatamente para o que você precisa. Se você já tiver um arquivo HTML, vai bastar apenas alterar a extensão para .ejs

1- Instale o EJS com: npm install ejs --save

2- Configure o servidor para reconhecer o ejs:

```
const app = require('express')();
const ejs = require('ejs');

Abaixo você informa para o express que quer usar o EJS
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Abaixo você informa onde as views estão
app.set('views', '/views');
```

3- Altera a extensão de .html para .ejs

Pronto! Agora você sua página já pode exibir conteúdo dinâmico em sua página.

Saiba mais como o EJS funciona no site do NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Opa, eu já imaginava isso. Aliás, já estou usando o .ejs , mas ainda não faço ideia de como recuperar o resultado de uma função assíncrona (pool.query) para o meu front. Vou dar uma pesquisada a mais sobre o EJS mesmo, vai que acho. Vlw pela dica mano.

Comment: E aí mano, blz? Andei pesquisando e era realmente disso que eu precisava, obg mesmo pelo norteamento.

Comment: Que bom que pude ajudar. =)